# Como converter uma tabela em json?

Tags: prisma

A tabela é assim:

```
tab = { 
       semana={"seg","ter","qua"},
       mês={"jan","fev","mar"},
       modelo={
              casaco={"pele","couro"}
       }            
}
```

Preciso que a saída fique no formato json para que o javascript interprete.

```
saída:  [{ "semana":["seg","ter,"qua"],
           "mês":["jan","fev","mar"],
           "modelo": { "casaco":["pele","couro"]
           }
}]
```

Comment: como você obteve esses valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usando a biblioteca [json.pris](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/prisma_forum/index.php?topic=60.msg114#msg114)**

a primeira linha chama a biblioteca, a segunda codifica a tabela para json e guarda em cadeiajson, a terceira é uma tratativa de erros.

```
local json = inclua 'json'            
cadeiajson, erros = json.cod(tab);   
se nao cadeia entao erro(erros) fim;
```

**A saída da tabela acima ficaria assim:**

```json
imprima(cadeiajson)

{"modelo":{"casaco":["pele", "couro"]}, "mes":["jan", "fev", "mar"], "semana":["seg", "ter", "qua"]}
```